# Finding new classes inside EAR Java EE Runtime

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have an EAR deployed on my JBoss server, and i would want to find classes from a specific package inside my EAR.
I tryed this:

```
private String[] loadNewClasses() throws Exception {
    String[] files = null;
    URL url = getClass().getResource("../../mypackage");
    String nameDir = url.getFile();
    File directory = new File(nameDir);
    if (directory.exists()) {
        files = directory.list();
    }
    return files;
}
```

Running this, it returns the URL's name correctly, something like `vfszip:/C:/java/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/myapp/deploy/myapp.ear/mymodule.jar/../mypackage/`. This path is right, but it skips the if() and doesn't take the classes inside this package.
There are ways to find classes inside package at runtime?

Comment: Is your deploy a folder or a compressed file?

Comment: Never ever try to access class path resources as java.io.File objects. Most of the time they are not file system objects.